# How are lambda functions implemented?

Tags: python, function, memory, lambda

I am a new newbie new to python, have coded for couple of years.
and I just got to know lambda.

I wonder how the lambda functions work in memory-wise.
Generally where are they stored in the computer memories and how are they called?

Do they become like in-line functions? Or do they have a pointer even though they will not be called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple explanation: A lambda is an *expression* that can be called as a function.

Its a shorthand way of writing "temporary functions" that can be used when needed, but then are no longer required after.

Just like anything else in Python, if there are no references to it - Python will eventually get rid of it (reclaim the memory/garbage collect/etc.) How and when it does this varies on which implementation of Python you are using.

There are certain advantages of lambdas though, since they are expressions they can be used in places that normal methods cannot.

Answer (score 8):

The `lambda` expression in Python is pretty much a shorthand way of writing one-line functions. Because it tends to be associated with functional styles of programming some people are uncomfortable with lambdas, preferring to write the equivalent short functions and use references to those functions in their code.

For any expression `expr(a, b, ...)` then `f = lambda: a, b, ... : expr(a, b, ...)` is closely equivalent to

```
def f(a, b, ...):
    return expr(a, b, ...)
```

You can use the `dis` module to disassemble the compiled Python bytecode for each to compare them, as below.

```
from dis import dis

flambda = lambda a, b: a + b

def ffunction(a, b):
    return a + b

dis(flambda)
print "-------------"
dis(ffunction)
```

The output from this simple program demonstrates that the compiled bytecodes are exactly the same.

```
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
-------------
  6           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Both objects are of type `<type function>` and only distinguishable by examining some obscure attributes such as `.func_name`, which for `ffunction` is `"ffunction"` whereas for `flambda` it is `"<lambda>"`.

Like all Python objects, once functions and lambdas go out of scope or are otherwise unbound from their last reference they become eligible for destruction and garbage collection. When that takes place depends upon the implementation.